# How to delete an entire row in Excel if same cell in preceding row is identical?

Tags: excel, vba

My excel spreadsheet contains 11 columns and 500k rows.  Each row is a sample from an 8-channel digital logic analyzer: column A is a time stamp; columns B through I are bit values (either a 1 or 0 in each cell); column J is a byte in binary created with CONCATENATE(B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I); and column K is that same byte in hexadecimal created with BIN2HEX(J).

The logic analyzer over-sampled the data considerably. I want to delete samples where the byte value did not change, keeping only the first sample in a series of sequential duplicates.  In other words, I want to change this:

```
A        B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J         K
0.67497  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  10011110  9E
0.67498  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  10011101  9D
0.67499  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  10011101  9D
0.67500  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  10011101  9D
0.67501  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  10011110  9E
```

to this:

```
A        B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J         K
0.67497  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  10011110  9E
0.67498  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  10011101  9D
0.67501  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  10011110  9E
```

If I run the following code after selecting cell K1, it deletes the over-samples as I desire, but it runs very slowly.  (It would take several days to finish.)

```
Sub DeleteOverSamples()
  Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
      ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```

How can I make this more efficient?  If the EntireRow.Delete is a time-consuming function, can I select multiple rows for deletion at a time (sometimes the repeated value repeats for hundreds of samples)?  Many thanks!

Comment: You can export your excel data as csv and process it with something saner.

Comment: (a) Why not just write the non-duplicate information to a new sheet, and then delete the old sheet?  (b) If you really want to use a deletion approach, have you changed columns J and K from formulas to values before running your deletion code?  If not, have you switched calculation to manual before running the code? (It may be recalculating everything every time there is a change to the sheet, because you may have exceeded the size of the calculation list.)  (c) Have you switched off `ScreenUpdating` before running the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete method is slow, and individual input/output of a cell's value is slow too.
Using a `Variant` array is fast.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim s As String

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    s = vDB(1, 11)

    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To r, 1 To c)
    For j = 1 To c
        vR(n, j) = vDB(1, j)
    Next j

    For i = 1 To r
        If s <> vDB(i, 11) Then
            n = n + 1
            For j = 1 To c
                vR(n, j) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
            s = vDB(i, 11)
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n, c) = vR

End Sub
```

Comment: Arrays give a speed increase from 10 seconds for my code processing using a single cell (column K) compared to 3 seconds with your code.  +1  (I was worried about reading 500,000 rows into an array, but it managed without running out of memory, so much better approach.)

Comment: @Dy.Lee, Thanks so much for your help!  This is fabulous!

Comment: @YowE3K, Although Dy.Lee's approach was slightly more optimized, I learned a lot from looking over your solution.  I want to thank you for your help on this, too.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will create a new sheet, copying the relevant values from the first sheet:

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim ws0 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim r0 As Long
    Dim r1 As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim startTime As Single
    startTime = Timer

    Set ws0 = ActiveSheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets.Add
    r0 = 1
    r1 = 1
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ws0.Cells(r0, 1).Value)
        If r0 = 1 Then
            ws1.Rows(r1).Range("A1:I1").Value = ws0.Rows(r0).Range("A1:I1").Value
            r1 = r1 + 1
        Else
            For c = 2 To 9
                If ws0.Cells(r0, c).Value <> ws0.Cells(r0 - 1, c).Value Then
                    ws1.Rows(r1).Range("A1:I1").Value = ws0.Rows(r0).Range("A1:I1").Value
                    r1 = r1 + 1
                End If
                Exit For
            Next
        End If
        r0 = r0 + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Finished in " & (Timer - startTime) & " seconds"
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tested this using the data you provided for the first few rows, and then replicating your last row for the next 499995 rows (except with column B being randomly selected between either `0` or `1`) and it took slightly over 20 seconds to copy approximately 250,000 rows of data.  Without the random effect in column B, it took just over 19 seconds to copy the 3 rows that you would expect.  A random effect in column I, instead of column B, took just over 28 seconds - which is probably the slowest it will go.

(It would be faster if it made use of your calculated column J or K, as it would only need to look at one cell each row instead of the 8 cells it currently looks at, but I wasn't sure whether you actually needed those columns or whether you only added them to make your existing code easier.)